# execCommand 'insertimage' is not working for local files in IE 11 on some computers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-11, insert-image

I'm trying to insert image from local folder using execCommand in IE11:

JS:

```
document.execCommand('insertImage', false, "C://issue.jpg");
```

It is working on one computer, but it is not working on other computer. For non working case I get the following:
[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/177tB.png)

It seems that it is some Windows or browser configuration issue. But I cannot find setting for this. Will you please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Where exactly is the page hosted? On an external web server, on a local server or on the filesystem (using file protocol)?

Comment: It is on external web server. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/sedoygosha/c6b5k4ps/ (Need to create issue.jpg in C:/ folder). If I create local page with the same code, it will be work fine in non working computer.

Comment: There are some options in Internet Options|Security|Internet Zone, click Edit and find Miscellanous section, where you can find some cross-domain options. I'm not going to try to translate my finnish option texts to english, but that's the section where you most likely will find the options to change.

Comment: When I run your fiddle in IE11, I get two errors to the console. Something like "file://C:/issue.jpg has made HTTPS insecure" and "XMLHTTPRequest: Network error 0x80070005 Access denied". These errors refer to a CORS problem, but I'm not sure which options should be changed.

Comment: @Teemu, thanks for your suggestion. But it did not help.
I enabled "Miscellaneous > Access data sources across domains" for non working computer. As I saied above it didn't help. 
I have the same options in Miscellaneous for working and non working computers. No effect.  

Note:  
I also see "HTTPS insecure" and "XMLHTTPRequest: Network error 0x80070005 Access denied" errors for working computer. So these errors are not related to the issue.